# Creating DOS bootable cd

Tags: bootable-media, disk-operating-system

I need to burn a cd which I will boot from to reset a password on Windows Server.

I am using Active Password Changer, but I get an error like so:

[image]

How can I create a "DOS bootable disk"? I have an ISO on the cd I thought that will work. The manual says I need DOS system files, where do I get these from?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you are simply running the application from the download.

As for creating Dos boot disks, if you have a floppy drive still, simply format and choose the `Copy system files` option, then open up the disk and copy the password change application.

I would also highly recommend [bootdisk.com](http://www.bootdisk.com/), they have a load of Dos and Windows bootdisks in a variety of formats that are ready to use.

If you go back to the [Download Page](http://www.password-changer.com/download.htm) you can download `Bootable CD-ROM ISO Image (Password Reset Disk)` which should just require burning and nothing else. To do this, use a tool such as [CDBurnerXP](http://www.cdburnerxp.se) (also available on [Ninite](http://www.ninite.com) for easy installation.)

May I also recommend [Offline NT Password and Registry Editor](http://home.eunet.no/pnordahl/ntpasswd/), I have had a lot of success with it and it also comes in an easy to use ISO that you can burn straight to a disk.

Comment: ok, mistake... il give you that one (added s to text, but the link was there).

Comment: right then ... but now we have the old problem of two answers to the same content :)

Comment: I have no floppy drive. I have to do this with CD.

Comment: If you have no floppy drive, you can create floppy image 
(ex. IMA file, with VirtualBox, VirtualPC ,etc).
1)Create a batch in Disk ISO, which mounts FDD image (from dos), using RawWrite utility.
2)Set that batch as boot file of ISO.